# ¿Se puede convertir un web Service rest en un soap?

Tags: rest, soap, bonita

Buenos días el motivo de mi pregunta es más informativa es si se puede realizar la conversión de un web service rest a un soap, ya que he leido varias información sobre indica que se puede realizar este procedimiento de soap a rest a través de Json la pregunta surge, por que estoy utilizado bonitasoft donde solo puede consumir web service soap (hasta donde tengo entendido) por ese motivo surge mi duda que si se puede realizar la conversión o transformación de un web service rest a soap en caso que se puede realizar me gustaría saber como puede realizar este procedimiento y sino se puede realizar el por que  gracias por su atención

Comment: Si tu creaste el WS si lo puedes cambiar pero si no lo creaste pues no, y es posible consumir ambos tipos de WS en Bonita.

Comment: vale mucha gracias  por la aclaración

Comment: No estoy familiarizado con BonitaSoft pero en todo caso si no se puede usar REST, es posible que crees un proxy soap web service con el cual te comunicarías e internamente usaría el rest web service original.

Comment: @MiguelFebres huy gracias miguel no sabia que podía realizar eso lo tendré en  cuanta al momento de consumir mis web service

Comment: @M.Gress como es posible consumir un web service rest en bonita?

Comment: Configuralo como si fuera SOAP con el conector que trae, te debe de funcionar.